# How do I repeat the event at different times weekly?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am currently using the google calendar API to insert events into a calendar. This is the RRULE that I am using for now that allows me to insert an event at the same time on specific days of the week every week.

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=30;BYDAY=TU,WE,FR;
```

Currently, events are being inserted at the same time on TU, WE & FR. However, I would like to insert the event at different times each day.

For example, the event should be between 3-4PM on Tuesdays and Wednesdays every week but between 5-7PM on Fridays. I want to avoid creating 3 separate weekly recurring events by calling the calendar API with different timings for each of these instances.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to do it with one RRULE. But you'd need just two events: one for TU and WE, another for FR.

Comment: In the actual application, I'll probably have more than just 3 days and different times each day. Anyway, thanks for the reply!

Comment: I have a similar requirement, how did you implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the [recurrence rules](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurring_events) on recurrent events. As it is described on the docs "*Events are called recurring if they repeat according to a defined schedule*". In this scenario you are effectively requesting different events albeit very similar ones because you need different schedules for each one.